# Make all list items same height as the tallest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a quiz i'm creating and there are 4 list items that are output on each question, the answer in each question differs in height...

[image]

I want to write a script that runs and sets all the divs to the same height as the biggest...

I have the following only if my answer has an image, it calculates the hiehgt before the image has finished loading and then sets the height so its fairly buggy, can anybody see a better way of me writing this?

```
function resizeAnswers(){
    var maxHeight = 23;

   $('.text-answers li').each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
   });

   $('.text-answers li').each(function() {
     $(this).height(maxHeight);
   });
}
```

Comment: ^ I think he means `$(window).on('load', function() { ... })`

Comment: @adeneo ah yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: You can temporarly adjust heights the way you are doing it, then listen to image loads individually. If their container expands beyong the maximum height previously set, then adjust the heights. You can also buffer all image loads that will occur within a specific timeframe to avoid changing the height too often. Waiting until all images are loaded using `$(window).load` is also possible, but might affect the user experience if you have many images that are slow to load.

Answer (score 1):

To wait until all images have loaded, call your code when the window is finished loading:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   resizeAnswers();
});
```

Note that this will wait for ALL images to load, which may be a problem depending on the nature of your site. If it is a problem, you can wait for just the images in your list items to load, but that is more complicated.

Also, you have this:

```
$('.text-answers li').each(function() {
   $(this).height(maxHeight);
});
```

But this will do the exact same thing:

```
$('.text-answers li').height(maxHeight);
```

jQuery will happily apply most operations to a set of elements.

Comment: `$(window).load` does not ensures all images are loaded :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It should but it isin't reliable.

Comment: I don't think it is unreliable on the window. It is definitely tricky and browser-dependent on image elements. But the `onload` event on the window will fire when the browser is done loading content. Of course this won't include, i.e., images you add to the dom after the fact, etc... See, for example, the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) which explicitly says "Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics". But I may be wrong, so feel free to point me to corrections.